Matching input parameter with comma seperated value in table
I have a data in table column like A,B,C,D now when I'm passing input as A then it should match values with A and pick respective details from other columns. Similarly when I pass B,C or D it should the query should match with table column values which are comma separated using SQL



Column A
Column B




X
A,B,C,D


Y
G



IF I pass whether A,B,C OR d AS INPUT RESULT SHOULD return X

Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

WITH 
    my_table AS (
        SELECT 'X' AS colA, 'A,B,C,D' AS colB FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Y' AS colA, 'G' AS colB FROM DUAL
    ),
    split_values AS (
        SELECT 
            colA,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(colB, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS colB_value
        FROM 
            my_table
        CONNECT BY 
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(colB, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        AND PRIOR colA = colA
        AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT 
    LISTAGG(colA, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colA) AS result
FROM 
    split_values
WHERE 
    colB_value = 'A' --or other values that you want to use as the input
GROUP BY 
    colA;

This will match the input value against the comma-separated list in colB and return the corresponding value of colA, aggregated with LISTAGG.

Hello,
Thanks for the response.
But this will create an issue when the comma separated values will have space b/w them like  A 1.0, A 2.0, A 3.0 . What will be the solution in that case.

Then you need to use a LIKE statement in the where clause (instead of colB_value = 'A' ). However, this seems really bad structured and configured datastructure to me as the data will end up unmaintainable by time.
